# html5 href download attribute issue

Tags: javascript, html, download, href

Until today this was working on Chrome to generate a KML file client-side:

```
<script>
  var kmlText = 'kml code here';
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", 'data:text/plain,' + kmlText);
  link.setAttribute("download", "Export.kml");
  link.innerHTML = "Download KML";
  document.getElementById("myDIV").appendChild(link);
</script>

<html>
  <div id="myDIV">Download</div>
</html>
```

Since recently the link would force a download but wouldn't accept the filename and extension on Chrome, defaulting to 'Download.txt'..
On Firefox it is working properly, as it was before on Chrome, too..

[Here's a fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WMkrW/)

Does someone have a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug in chrome. I can't reproduce it on my desktop.

You should file a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Why the downvote?? @Iovasoa, if it is working on your desktop, it can't be a bug in Chrome, but rather some issue with my browser settings..

Comment: The downvote is not by me.

It can still be a bug in chrome. We might not have the same version, be under the same OS, ... Not all bugs affect all users.

The best thing to do is to talk to chromium's developers. They are really opened to discussion. File a bug and talk to them.

Comment: Thanks @Iovasoa. I even tried to re-install Chrome, to no evail. I'll best send a bug report as suggested by you.

Comment: ..this has been an issue before: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373182. However, there is a workaround with `blob()` I found here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download. See this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/UZrzW/